# How much data could be stored into a Google App Engine, application?

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, cloud

Answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462055/is-it-correct-that-developers-have-read-only-access-to-the-filesystem-on-app-eng) and searching for references I have this doubt my self:

*How much data could be stored into a Google App Engine, application?

If I'm reading well [this](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html#Datastore) table:

```
Resources    | Free daily  |  Free Max Rate  | Daily Billing enable           | Max Rate Billing
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Stored Data  | 1 gigabyte  |    None         |  1 gigabytes free; no maximum  | None
```

Does it means you can storage as much as you want for free ( as long as it is 1 gb daily? )

:-o

**EDIT**

Mmhh I was wrong.

I have found also the official link that answer my own question:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/billing.html

```
Resource           |    Unit        |   Unit cost
-------------------------------------------------
Outgoing Bandwidth |    gigabytes   |   $0.12

-------------------------------------------------
Incoming Bandwidth |    gigabytes   |   $0.10

-------------------------------------------------
CPU Time           |    CPU hours   |   $0.10

-------------------------------------------------
Stored Data        | gigabytes per month |  $0.15
-------------------------------------------------
Recipients Emailed |    recipients |    $0.0001
```

So, using 7.6 gb of storage wouldcost $1 USD/month   :-o Still, very cheap. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I read that to mean 1 GB stored during the course of a day, not added in a day, so in other words you can have up to 1 GB of storage for free. If you store more, calculated daily, you have to pay for that additional storage. There is no maximum on how much you can store, you just get billed for it.

Comment: Yishai, so, am I right by saying 6.6 gb would cost 1 uds per month?

Comment: @Oscar, that is what it says (although in practice you have to pay for uploading that data, so put that in your budget as well). Amazon is the same price (cheaper after the first 50 TB). http://aws.amazon.com/s3/#pricing